# Is it possible to detect whether whatsapp is installed?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, whatsapp

On an iPhone device, on an HTML page you can always compose an sms (via an sms:1234567890 URL), and if WhatsApp is installed, you can compose a WhatsApp message (via the [WhatsApp protocol](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013)).

Is it possible to detect such features on an HTML page?

Comment: You can detect if whatsapp is installed by using the example provided by the WhatsApp protocol link you provided. `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]` will return `YES` if the app is installed. I'm basing this comment on the title of the question, but not sure it answers the content of the question.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is you can't do this fron JavaScript. Is there à JavaScript equivalent of this call?

Comment: somethink like this https://gist.github.com/mcxiaoke/c2dd7d24c31c5bd2d724 its work for me

Answer (score 3):

Following a few hours of research + consulting with top experts I came to the conclusion that **there is no legitimate way** of achieving the goal of detecting whether a specific app is installed on the device without having the browser re-direct to the app if it is installed.

In iOS for example, there was an app just removed from the App Store because of violating the rules: SysSecInfo. The app managed to pull list of all running processes for example.

From: https://www.sektioneins.de/en/blog/16-05-09-system-and-security-info.html

> See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/703/ "App
>   Detection" starting at 08:34
>
> During this talk they discuss several APIs used to gather information
>   about processes currently running on your system (around 12:12 in the
>   video) and claimed to have fixed them. However as so often Apple has
>   only partially fixed the problems they claim to have fixed. Therefore
>   they have actually never stopped malicious applications from gathering
>   information about what other applications run currently on your
>   device, but only removed access to detail information that is only
>   relevant for harmless system information tools anyway.
>
> System and Security Info is therefore still able to show the list of
>   running processes and enriches this list with information from the
>   codesigning information including the list of entitlements running
>   processes have.